# Pullback metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, submanifold

Let $M^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ oriented submanifold with the induced euclidean metric. For $t \in \mathbb{R}$, let $\psi_t : M \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, $p \mapsto p + tN(p)$, where $N$ is the unit normal vector field over $M$. For small values of $t$, $\psi_t$ is an inmersion and $(d\psi_t)(T_pM) = T_pM$. In fact,

$$
(d\psi_t)_p(v) = v + t dN_p(v), \quad \forall v \in T_pM.
$$

Let $g_t$ the metric over $M$ obtained from pullback of the scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, that is:

$$
g_t(v,w) = \langle (d\psi_t)_p(v),(d\psi_t)_p(w)\rangle.
$$

Since $d\psi_t$ is a vector space isomorphism, $N_t = N$. This does not mean that the Weingarten $A_t$ endomorphism of $(M,g_t)$ does not depend of $t$. My teacher said that

$$
(II_t)(v,w) = -g_t((dN_t)_p(v),w) \stackrel{(*)}{=} -\langle (dN_t)_p(v), (d\psi_t)_p(w)\rangle
$$

I can't see why $(*)$ is true. I thought that might be

$$
-\langle (d\psi_t)_p((dN_t)_p(v)), (d\psi_t)_p(w)\rangle
$$

Finally we must obtain

$$
(II_t)_p(v,w) = g_{p}\left(A_{p} v, w-t A_{p} w\right)
$$

Edited:

The second fundamental form $II_t$ of $(M,g_t)$ is

$$
\begin{split}
 (II_t)_p(e_i,e_j) = k_i(p)\left(1 - tk_j(p)\right) \delta_{ij}.
\end{split}
$$

where $\{e_i\}$ is a ortogonal basis of principal directions of $(M,g)$. This base is not $g_t$-ortonormal, but
$$
\left\{\frac{1}{1-t k_{1}(p)} e_{1},\dots, \frac{1}{1-t k_{n}(p)} e_{n},\right\}
$$
it is and $II_t$ diagonalize. All of this is strictly directed with the tube formula of compact hypersurfaces of euclidean space
$$
\int_{\Omega_r} f d v_{g_{0}}=\int_{p \in M}\left(\int_{0}^{r} f\left(p+t N_{p}\right) \prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1-t k_{i}(p)\right) d t\right) d v_{g}
$$
where $\Omega_r$ is the interior half tube of $M$, i.e, the image of $F$. In particular, for $f \equiv 1$

$$
vol(\Omega_r)= \sum_{i = 0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\dfrac{r^{i+1}}{i+1}\int_{M}\sigma_i(k_1,\dots,k_n) \ d vol_M,
$$

(Weyl tube formula or Steiner formula)

Comment: "Since $d\psi_t$ is a vector space isomorphism, $N_t=N$." This is not valid reasoning. If the tangent space at $\psi_t(p)$ is exactly the tangent space at $p$ as a subspace of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$, then this means the normal vectors are equal. Isomorphism tells you nothing. In addition, the formula for $d\psi_t(v)$ is just wrong. It should be $v+t\,dN_p(v)$, right?

Comment: Sanity check. Suppose $M$ is a (round) sphere with radius $a$ and we take $N$ to be the outward-pointing normal. Does your teacher's formula give the right result for the second fundamental form of $\psi_t(M)$?

Comment: Yes, I am going to correct the differential map, it was a typo. On the other hand, my teacher's computations are corrected, because he obtain the tube formula in the euclidean case.

Comment: Thank you, Ted. But I have a doubt. We have $(M,g)$ and $(M,g_t)$ and the tangent space among $d\psi_t$ is the same. This space is $n$-dimensional and we are working in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} = T_pM \oplus \langle N\rangle$. The vector $(N_t)_p \not \in T_pM$, then $N_p = \pm (N_t)_p$, for all $t \in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ (keep in mind $N_0 = N$). By a continuity plot in the $t$-variable, we choose $N_t \equiv N$. This doesnt mean that the Weingarten map does not depend of $t$, because it's a self-adjoint map respect $(g_t)_p$.

Comment: Yes, of course, because you're really doing the Weingarten map on different submanifolds. I think about this stuff a little differently, I admit, but you should end up with principal curvatures $k_i/(1+tk_i)$ for $M_t$. Do we agree on that?

Comment: Well, I'm assuming $dN_p(e_i) = -k_i(p) e_i$. But the sign is not a problem to me. Thank you very much for your help! I will continue working on this topics